# Pass $page_id to new WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, page-template

Probably pretty simple and more PHP-related than pure WP, but how would one pass the `$page_id` generated in the first code snip into the `new WP_Query ()` in the second code snip?

What I need to do - in a page template - is **dynamically** get the current page ID and pass that to the new WP_Query in order to display content for that current page. This is for a page template that will display different content according to the page_id, somewhat opposite of what a page template usually does with the loop.

I don't need pagination or anything else; the new queries will display small amounts of content in a jQuery UI tab structure.

**Global wp_query to get current page ID (and echo it for testing purposes):**

```
<?php global
$wp_query;
$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
echo $page_id; ?>
```

**Standard new WP_Query for the content:**

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( **need $page_ID here** ); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You've got a page id, from the first snippet, but what do you want to compare it to in your wp_query constructor?

Comment: I want the page_id to be the WP_Query value, as noted above in the second code snip.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. If $page_id is 4, is this what you want to do: $my_query = new WP_Query(4)??

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. I want to pass the page_id to the query so the template displays content according to the page_id.

Comment: ok, but you can't just put a value as the parameter - you need to at the very least do this: new WP_Query( 'page_id=4' );

Comment: Ah, yes; you're right. It needs to be formatted with the "page_id=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the same page and you just need to display the same page's content again, you can just call `the_content` multiple times.

To answer your question, however:

You'll use the `page_id` argument for WP_Query (you could also probably use `p`).  You can even remove your `global $wp_query` and the like.

```
<?php
$new_query = new WP_Query(array(
   'page_id' => get_queried_object_id()
));
```

Comment: Looks like that should work, but your new query with get_queried_object_id just gives me white space, so there's an error somewhere in it. What I want to do is use a page template that will dynamically display different content according to the page_id, opposite of what a page template usually does with the loop.

Comment: My mistake; this works fine. Even with removing the `global $wp_query`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need first snippet. Just use [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) on second snippet.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( ** use get_the_ID() here ** ); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: not sure why you need query there though. Page content is already available for you.

Comment: This is for a page template that will dynamically display different content according to the page_id.